# Shopware 6 - Own Free Product is not editable

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

We are using our own Free Products plugin in which we programmatically set the price of the free products to zero. like so:

```php
$lineItem = $this->factory->create([
  'type' => LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE,
  'referencedId' => $item->getProductId(),
], $context);
$lineItem->setRemovable(false);
$lineItem->setStackable(false);
$lineItem->setLabel($item->getName());
$lineItem->addExtension('scgItem', new ArrayEntity([ "isAdded" => true, "isPreventSale" => $item->isPreventSale() ]));
$lineItem->setPriceDefinition(new QuantityPriceDefinition(0, new TaxRuleCollection(), 1))->setPrice(new CalculatedPrice(0, 0, new CalculatedTaxCollection(), new TaxRuleCollection()));
$lineItem->setPrice(new CalculatedPrice(0, 0, new CalculatedTaxCollection(), new TaxRuleCollection()));
```

A customer of ours has brought the following issue to our attention:

The customer is facing a problem where the services he is using cannot handle a 0€ product, so he would like to set the price to 1€ (and reduce the main price by 1€).

When the price of the free product is changed, as shown in the attached images, Shopware automatically creates a new product. Could you please explain to us why this behavior is occurring?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is this code located? In which subscriber / controller etc. ?

Comment: @Alex in the CartDataCollectorInterface